# How to extract the inner text or inner html from a html node in R

Tags: html, r, rvest, xml2

I am trying to extract the date from a html node using R. This script used to work fine and I think perhaps the webpage has changed somewhat and now it returns N/A.

```
webpage = read_html('https://www.longpaddock.qld.gov.au/aussiegrass')
results = webpage %>% html_nodes("#graph-out-last-updated")
webpage_date_chr = html_text(results)
webpage_date_chr  ## This should print the date!!!
```

The image shows the node and the date, but I cannot extract the date.
[image]
Any help would be amazing!!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the page is a dynamic site, so the page needs to be loaded first before the data can be scraped. You'll need to use a headless browser, like that used in the `chromote` package.

I've edited your code to something that returned the date "21 June 2023" for me.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(chromote)
library(rvest)

chromote_scrape <- function(url) {
  b$Page$navigate(url)
  Sys.sleep(2)
  x <- b$DOM$getDocument()
  x <- b$DOM$querySelector(x$root$nodeId, "body")
  read_html(b$DOM$getOuterHTML(x$nodeId)$outerHTML)
}

b <- ChromoteSession$new()
webpage = chromote_scrape('https://www.longpaddock.qld.gov.au/aussiegrass')
results = webpage %>% html_nodes("#graph-out-last-updated")
webpage_date_chr = html_text(results)
webpage_date_chr  ## This should print the date!!!
```

For more info, read section 25.7 of R4DS here: https://r4ds.hadley.nz/webscraping.html

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. The script was originally using the system() command to get the page as html and save it. But it was giving me the same results.. In any case, this advice is super helpful and chromote looks great!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Those details are sourced from a single JSON file and guessing from the URL, that endpoint should be fairly stable: `https://www.longpaddock.qld.gov.au/data/aussie-grass-graphs.json`

Structure itself is nothing special:
[image]
Yet not ideal for automatic rectangling to data.frame, here's one example how one might approach this with `purrr`, `tibble` and `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

grass_graphs <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.longpaddock.qld.gov.au/data/aussie-grass-graphs.json")

lga <- grass_graphs %>% 
  # turn list inside out, top level transforms from 
  # (ACT, NSW, NT, ...) to (lga, subibra)
  list_transpose() %>% 
  # work only with lga items
  pluck("lga") %>%
  # turn list into 2 column name-value tibble, values being lists
  tibble::enframe(name = "region", value = "lga_list") %>% 
  # unnest list columns to longer or wider, one level at a time
  unnest_longer(lga_list, indices_to = "lga") %>% 
  unnest_wider(lga_list) %>% 
  unnest_wider(gif:txt, names_sep = ".") %>% 
  # convert unix timestamps
  mutate(across(ends_with("date"), ~ as_datetime(.x) %>% as_date()))
lga
#> # A tibble: 555 × 8
#>    region gif.size gif.date   pdf.size pdf.date   txt.size txt.date   lga       
#>    <chr>     <int> <date>        <int> <date>        <int> <date>     <chr>     
#>  1 ACT       44134 2018-07-31   174970 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 Act       
#>  2 NSW       43763 2018-07-31   176189 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 AlburyCit…
#>  3 NSW       44483 2018-07-31   176482 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 ArmidaleR…
#>  4 NSW       43769 2018-07-31   175293 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 BallinaSh…
#>  5 NSW       44956 2018-07-31   177756 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 Balranald…
#>  6 NSW       44267 2018-07-31   176878 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 BathurstR…
#>  7 NSW       43701 2018-07-31   173621 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 BaysideCo…
#>  8 NSW       44216 2018-07-31   176428 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 BegaValle…
#>  9 NSW       43996 2018-07-31   175817 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 Bellingen…
#> 10 NSW       43992 2018-07-31   176204 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 BerriganS…
#> # ℹ 545 more rows
```

Extract file sizes and dates for a single Shire / LGA:

```
lga %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(lga, "Aurukun"))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 8
#>   region gif.size gif.date   pdf.size pdf.date   txt.size txt.date   lga        
#>   <chr>     <int> <date>        <int> <date>        <int> <date>     <chr>      
#> 1 QLD       51200 2018-07-31   184589 2023-06-20   286953 2023-06-20 AurukunShi…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thankyou! This info will probably be useful for the next pile of issues I run into as well!